# Which preposition to use in "gettarsi a capofitto sul/nel lavoro" to say "throw yourself into work"?

Tags: prepositions

> gettarsi a capofitto **sul** lavoro
>
> {or}: gettarsi a capofitto **nel** lavoro

The equivalent French expression "se plonger **dans**  son travail" invariably employs the preposition "dans" corresponding to "in" in Italian. The same goes for "throw yourself **into** work" in English; you never say "throw yourself onto work".

A few bilingual dictionaries that I have consulted have it as "gettarsi a capofitto in ...". The thing is that I came across "gettarsi a capofitto sul lavoro" in an email message professionally translated from English -- and written in a colloquial tone. As such, I figured it was unlikely that a grammatical error like this would slip in.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because to answer it it suffices to look for _capofitto_ in any dictionary.

Comment: @DaG Unfortunately, it does not suffice, as I came across "sul lavoro" somewhere in a professionally translated sentence. Which prompted this question in the first place. :)

Comment: @Alone-zee Maybe you can  add to the question that you found *sul lavoro* in (some?) Italian texts, for added context.

Comment: I agree with @DenisNardin: a general rule to ask good questions on Stack Exchange is [sharing your research](https://italian.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: So, please mention the dictionaries you have browsed before asking the question and the texts that appear to contradict them, so we have not to redo the research you have apparently already done.

Comment: Moreover: «The same goes for "throw yourself into work" in English; you never say "throw yourself onto work".» Parallels with other languages are less than useful (independently on this particular case). There are innumerable case where, say, Italian and English use prepositions differently: interested in/interessato a, depend on/dipendere da, concerned with/riguardante, search for/cercare, and so on.

Answer (score 3):

As you can see on [Treccani dictionary](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/capofitto) or [Sabatini Coletti dictionary](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/C/capofitto.shtml) one says ***gettarsi*** or ***buttarsi a capofitto in qualcosa***. So in this case, it would be

> gettarsi / buttarsi a capofitto **nel** lavoro.

Preposition "su" used with verb "gettarsi" has the nuance of "above something". So, for instance, one may say

> gettarsi ***sul*** letto

with the meaning of "on the bed", or, in a figurative way,

> gettarsi ***sul*** nemico.